# Python 3.6 - SciKitLearn - module has no attribute 'CategoricalEncoder'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import

I'm following along in the book 'Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow'.
Right now, I'm trying to use sklearn's [`CategoricalEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html), but python is refusing to accept it.

This is my code right now:

```
from util.fetch import *
from data.data import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from sklearn.model_selection import *
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
from sklearn.pipeline import *
import pandas.plotting as pdp


def main():

    #
    #   Basic Data Exploration
    #

    fetch_housing_data()
    housing = load_housing_data()

    housing.hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15))
    plot.savefig(os.path.join('datasets', 'histogram.png'))

    #
    #   Creating a Test Set
    #

    train_set, test_set = train_test_split(housing, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    housing['income_cat'] = np.ceil(housing['median_income'] / 1.5)
    housing['income_cat'].where(housing['income_cat'] < 5, 5.0, inplace=True)

    split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing['income_cat']):
        strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
        strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]

    for set_ in (strat_train_set, strat_test_set):
        set_.drop('income_cat', axis=1, inplace=True)

    #
    #   In-depth exploration of Training Data
    #

    housing = strat_train_set.copy()

    #
    #       Plot Geographical Data
    #

    housing.plot(
        kind='scatter',
        x='longitude',
        y='latitude',
        alpha=0.4,
        s=housing['population']/100,
        label='population',
        figsize=(10,7),
        c='median_house_value',
        cmap=plot.get_cmap('jet'),
        colorbar=True)

    #plot.show()
    plot.savefig(os.path.join('datasets','geodata.png'))

    corr_matrix = housing.corr()

    print(corr_matrix['median_house_value'].sort_values(ascending=False))

    attributes = ['median_house_value','median_income','total_rooms','housing_median_age']
    pdp.scatter_matrix(housing[attributes], figsize=(12,8))
    plot.savefig(os.path.join('datasets', 'scatter_matrix.png'))

    housing.plot(
        kind='scatter',
        x='median_income',
        y='median_house_value',
        alpha=0.1)
    plot.savefig(os.path.join('datasets', 'median_income-median_house_value.png'))

    housing['rooms_per_household'] = housing['total_rooms'] / housing['households']
    housing['bedrooms_per_room'] = housing['total_bedrooms'] / housing['total_rooms']
    housing['population_per_household'] = housing['population'] / housing['households']

    corr_matrix = housing.corr()

    corr_file = open(os.path.join('datasets','median_house_value_corr.txt'), 'w+')
    corr_file.write(str(corr_matrix['median_house_value'].sort_values(ascending=False)))
    corr_file.close()

    #
    #   Preparing data for Machine Learning Algorithms
    #
    housing = strat_train_set.drop('median_house_value', axis=1)
    housing_labels = strat_train_set['median_house_value'].copy()

    num_attribs = list(housing_num)
    cat_attribs = ['ocean_proximity']

    num_pipeline: Pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attribs)),
        ('imputer', Imputer(strategy='median')),
        ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ])

    cat_pipeline: Pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attribs)),
        ('cat_encoder', CategoricalEncoder(encoding='onehot-dense'))
    ])

    full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
        ('num_pipeline', num_pipeline),
        ('cat_pipeline', cat_pipeline),
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is giving me problems toward the end though, when it gets to line 123, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***/Housing/main.py", line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "***/Housing/main.py", line 123, in main
    ('cat_encoder', CategoricalEncoder(encoding='onehot-dense'))
NameError: name 'CategoricalEncoder' is not defined
```

(I've censored paths in the stacktrace)

I've tried all kinds of things to get it to import right, but I've failed unfortunately. It's not having any trouble using any of the other sklearn classes, just the CategoricalEncoder. The book mentioned that the CategoricalEncoder class is rather recent and might not be out yet, is this the case?

I've checked the sklearn documentation and they provide links to the source-code that implements this, when I look at the corresponding file in my virtual environment though, I'm missing at least 400-500 lines of code. I'm using PyCharm and letting it install all dependencies as they are needed.

(I'm aware that the pipelines at the end aren't running right now, since the script stops executing before those, it's not really an issue...)

Comment: `from something import *` is not good practice at all, it's flooding your namespace with allsorts. In this case, if you'd been explicit in your imports, it would be much easier to track down the error; likely they refactored the library and it's now accessed in a different way. With your current approach to importing, I don't know which module it's supposed to come from.

Comment: Thank you, just to be clear, I should do ```from scikit import Pipeline``` etc., right?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Or just import the module and use as `scikit.Pipeline` (which might be less practical with a module like `scikit`) or `import scikit as sc` then you could use `sc.Pipeline`. Anything that lets you know which module it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CategoricalEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) is only available in the development version 0.20.dev0. This version will not be installed automatically by pip, conda or any other package manager and you will need to specifically install it if you want to use that version.

In this case you will have to follow the instructions in [Sklean - Advanced Installation - Install Bleeding Edge](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-bleeding-edge) to get the development version.